# What does this error mean: 'Property 'then' does not exist on type '{ <T>(this: Observable<T>)'?

Tags: angular, http, promise

I am getting a weird error I have not encountered before and could not find a post related.

The error is:

```sh
Property 'then' does not exist on type '{ <T>(this: Observable<T>): Promise<T>; <T>(this: Observable<T>, PromiseCtor: PromiseConstructor)...'.
```

I am switching from using `.subscribe` to use `.toPromise().then()`. I have done the same thing on several other HTTP requests with no issue. Not sure how this one is different.

In a service I have the function:

```js
getData(user: string) {
    var url = some url
    let httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            some headers
          }),
          withCredentials: true };
    return this.http.get(url, httpOptions);
  }
```

Then in a component I have

```js
this._apiService.getData(lan).toPromise.then((information: any) =>
   {
        console.log(information)
   });
```

I did something something very similar on three other `http` requests without getting this issue and the service call is setup exactly the same and so is the component functions. What does this error mean?

Comment: Don't forget the parentheses: `.toPromise().then(...)`.

Comment: [`toPromise`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable#topromise-) is a function.

Comment: Simple typo, can close the question now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parentheses()

```
toPromise().then( /*your code here*/)
```

Here is an example https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-promises/